# How to use annotations instead of web.xml in Restlet

Tags: rest, restlet-2.3.1

I want to remove Configuration of Application in web.xml and want to do it using annotation like jersey in Restlet.

1- Is it possible?
2- If yes then How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Solution in Servlet 3 Done this using @WebServlet annotation